# For $n, m \ge 0, n+m\ge 2$, evaluate $W_{m, n} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n}} $.

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, riemann-zeta

This is derived from my answer to [$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}W_{m,k}f_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n+x}{n(n+1)}\right)^k f_k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784351/sum-m-0-inftyxm-sum-k-0-inftyw-m-kf-k-sum-n-1-infty-frac1)

For $n, m \ge 0, n+m\ge 2$,
what is the value of
$W_{m, n}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n}}
$.

My results:

- From the definition \begin{align*}
  W_{0, n} &= \zeta(n)  \\
  W_{m, 0} &= \zeta(m)-1  \text{.}
  \end{align*}
- Recurrence from which everything else follows:
  $$  W_{m, n} = W_{m-1, n}-W_{m, n-1}  \text{.}  $$
- Explicit values:
  \begin{align*}
  W_{1, n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (-1)^k\zeta(n-k) + (-1)^{n-1} \\
  W_{m, 1} &=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \zeta(n-k) + m  \text{.}
  \end{align*}

I have not yet worked out the general formula for $W_{m,n}$.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic:  Is there a question here?  Is it, "What is the formula for general $W_{m,n}$?"

Comment: I have a related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783981/a-name-for-w-m-n-binomnm-sum-k-0-max-m-n-1-zeta-k-opera

where I've identified the coeffecients as having a Mellin transform inverse pair, I've also got a paper in progress at https://github.com/crowlogic/a/blob/master/TransferOperatorOfTheHarmonicSawtoothMap.pdf 

there is some already known stuff about it at http://linas.org/math/gkw.pdf

as well.

It is derived from the transfer operator of the Lüroth series map which you can read about at the link above

Comment: Yep, that is the same question, aside from the binomial coefficient. I didn't see an explicit formula for the coefficients, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues are given by 
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{cl}
    \lambda_m & = W_{m, m}\\
    & = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{m + 1} (n + 1)^{m + 1}}\\
    & = \sum_{n = 0}^{\frac{m}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{(- 1)^m}{4}} \zeta (2
    n) \frac{2 (- 1)^{m + 1 - 2 n} \Gamma (2 m - 2 n + 2)}{\Gamma (m + 2 - 2
    n) \Gamma (m + 1)}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \frac{m}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{(- 1)^m}{4} = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4,
  5, \ldots] {where} m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9, \ldots
\end{equation}
This form of the function means that $Y_{m, n, k} = 0$ when $k$ is odd and $m
= n$ so that
\begin{equation}
  Y_{m, m, k} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    0 & k {is} {odd}\\
    \frac{2 (- 1)^{m + 1 - k} \Gamma (2 m - k + 2)}{\Gamma (m + 2 - k) \Gamma
    (m + 1)} & k {is} {even}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
when $m \neq n$ the off-diagonals involve also odd-integer values of $\zeta$
so we need to find a general expression for $Y_{m, n, k}$ and not just the
diagonals $Y_{m, m, k}$
where

$$\begin{array}{ll}
  W_{m, n} & = \binom{n}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k + 1)^{n + 1}
  k^{m + 1}}\\
  & = \binom{n}{m} \sum_{k = 0}^{\max (m, n) + 1} \zeta (k) Y_{m, n, k}
\end{array}$$

also

\begin{equation}
  Y_{m, n, 0} = \frac{2 (- 1)^{m + n + 1} \Gamma (m + n + 2)}{(n + 1) \Gamma
  (m + 1)^2 \Gamma (n + 1 - m)} = - \frac{2}{\Gamma (m)^2} \prod_{k = 1}^{2 n
  - 1} (- 1)^{n - 1} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    1 & k = m\\
    n - m + k & k \neq m
  \end{array} \right. \label{Y0}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation} \begin{array}{lfl}
  \hat{y}_{n, 0} (s) & = \sum_{m = 0}^n \frac{Y_{m, n, 0}}{m + s}\\
  & = \sum_{m = 0}^n \frac{\frac{2 (- 1)^{m + n + 1} \Gamma (m + n + 2)}{(n +
  1) \Gamma (m + 1)^2 \Gamma (n + 1 - m)}}{m + s}\\
  & = \mathit{} - 2 \hspace{0.17em} \frac{(- 1)^n_{} 3F2  \left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \begin{array}{lllll}
      s &  & - n &  & n + 2
    \end{array}\\
    \begin{array}{lll}
      1 &  & s + 1
    \end{array}
  \end{array} ; \hspace{0.17em} 1 \right]}{s}
\end{array} \end{equation}

where 3F2 is a generalized hypergeometric function and

\begin{equation}
  Y_{m, n, 1} = 0 \label{Y1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  Y_{m, n, 2} = 0^{m + n} + \frac{(- 1)^{m + n} \Gamma (n + m)}{\Gamma (m +
  1)^2 \Gamma (n - m)} \label{Y2}
\end{equation}
and the coeffecients of $\zeta (3)$ are simply related to a shifted version of
the coeffecients of $\zeta (2)$
\begin{equation}
  Y_{m, n, 3} = Y_{m, n - 1, 2} \label{Y3}
\end{equation}

$\begin{array}{ll}
  Y_{m, n, 4} & = {Res} (\hat{y}_{n, 4} (s), s = - m)\\
  & = \lim_{s = - m} (s + m) \hat{y}_{n, 4} (s)\\
  & = {Res} (\hat{y}_{n, 4} (s), s = - m)\\
  & = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    0 & n \leqslant 2\\
    \frac{(- 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m!^{})^2} \left( \prod_{k = 0}^{m - 1} (n - k)
    \right) \left( \prod_{k = 1}^{m - 2} (n + k) \right) (n^2 - (m + 1) n + m
    (m - 1)) & n \geqslant 3
  \end{array} \right.
\end{array}$

we also have

$Y_{m, n, 5} = \frac{(- 1)^{1 + n - m}  \left( m^2 + n^2 - 3 \hspace{0.17em} m
+ n \right)  \prod_{k = 1}^{2 \hspace{0.17em} m - 2} (k + 1 + n - m)}{(m!)^2}$

if we write the polynomials specifying the coefficients as hyper-geometric functions we find

\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{ll}
    y_{n, 0} (x) & = 2 \hspace{0.17em} (- 1)^{n + 1}_{} 2F1 (0 - n, n + 2 ;
    \hspace{0.17em} 1 ; \hspace{0.17em} x)\\
    y_{n, 1} (x) & = 0\\
    y_{n, 2} (x) & = \hspace{0.17em} (- 1)^n_{} 2F1 (n, 1 - n ;
    \hspace{0.17em} 1 ; \hspace{0.17em} x)\\
    y_{n, 3} (x) & = (- 1)^{n + 1} 2F1 (n - 1, 2 - n ; 1 ; x)\\
    y_{n, 4} (x) & = (- 1)^n 4F3 \left( \begin{array}{l}
      \begin{array}{lll}
        {}[0 - n] & [n - 1] & \left[ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}
        \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6 \hspace{0.17em} n +
        1} \right]
      \end{array}\\
      \begin{array}{ll}
        {}[1]  & \left[ - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}
        \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6 \hspace{0.17em} n +
        1} \right]
      \end{array}
    \end{array} ; x \right)\\
    y_{n, 5} (x) & = (- 1)^{n + 1}_{} 4F3 \left( \begin{array}{l}
      \begin{array}{lll}
        {}[n] & [- n - 1] & \left[ - \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} 
        \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 4 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 - 4 \hspace{0.17em} n +
        9} \right]
      \end{array}\\
      \begin{array}{ll}
        {}[1]  & \left[ - \frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{-
        4 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 - 4 \hspace{0.17em} n + 9} \right]
      \end{array}
    \end{array} ; x \right)
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
where $[a \pm b]$ is actually two elements, $[a + b]$ and $[a - b]$

Comment: Very impressive. You have certainly taken this much further than I could.  Accepted.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to know the entire formula

Comment: You might find the related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787558/can-s2-n-1-s-n-n-1-frac-prodn-2-k-1-s-k-p/2787960#2787960 interesting

Answer (score 2):

Just to be complete,
here is everything
I have got so far,
including two recurrences
at the end
that don't seem to be
of much use.

According to Wolfy,

$
W_{1,1}
=1\\
W_{1,2}
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-1\\
W_{2, 1}
=2-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\\
W_{2, 2}
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3}-3\\
W_{1, 3}
=\zeta(3)+1-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\\
W_{3, 1}
=-\zeta(3)-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}+3\\
W_{2, 3}
=\zeta(3)+4-\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}\\
W_{3,2}
=\zeta(3)+\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}-6\\
W_{3, 3}
=10-\pi^2\\
$

$W_{0, n}
=\zeta(n)
$.

$W_{m, 0}
=\zeta(m)-1
$.

$\begin{array}\\
W_{m+1, n+1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^{m+1}k^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)k(k+1)^mk^{n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n}}(\frac1{k}-\frac1{k+1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^{m+1}k^{n}}\\
&=W_{m, n+1}-W_{m+1, n}\\
\end{array}
$

or
$W_{m, n}
=W_{m-1, n}-W_{m, n-1}
$.

$m=0$:

$W_{1, n+1}\\
=W_{0, n+1}-W_{1, n}\\
=\zeta(n+1)-W_{1, n}\\
=\zeta(n+1)-\zeta(n)+W_{1, n-1}\\
=...\pm\zeta(2)\mp 1\\
$

so
$W_{1,n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (-1)^k\zeta(n-k)
+(-1)^{n-1}
$.

$n=0$:

$W_{m+1, 1}\\
=W_{m, 1}-W_{m+1, 0}\\
=W_{m, 1}-\zeta(m+1)+1\\
=-\zeta(m+1)+1+W_{m, 1}\\
=-\zeta(m+1)-\zeta(m)+2+W_{m-1, 1}\\
=...-\zeta(2)+m-1+W_{1, 1}\\
$

so
$W_{m, 1}
=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \zeta(n-k)
+m
$.

Check:

$(3, 3)\\
=(2, 3)-(3, 2)\\
=((1, 3)-(2,2))-((2,2)-(3, 1))\\
=(1, 3)-2(2, 2)+(3, 1)\\
=(z(3)-z(2)+1)-2((1, 2)-(2, 1))+(-z(3)-z(2)+3)\\
=-2z(2)+4)-2((1, 2)-(2, 1))\\
=-2z(2)+4)-2(z(2)-1-(-z(2)+2)\\
=-6z(2)+10\\
=-\pi^2+10\\
$

$\begin{array}\\
W_{m, n}-\zeta(m+n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n}}-\frac1{k^{m+n}})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}(\frac{1}{(k+1)^m}-\frac1{k^{m}})\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}(\frac{(k+1)^m-k^m}{(k+1)^mk^{m}})\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(k+1)^mk^{m+n}}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}k^j\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(k+1)^mk^{m+n-j}}\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, m+n-j}\\
\end{array}
$

so,
isolating the
$j=0$ term,

$W_{m, m+n}\\
=\zeta(m+n)-W_{m, n}-\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, m+n-j}\\
=\zeta(m+n)-W_{m, n}-\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, n+j}\\
=\zeta(m+n)-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, n+j}
$.

Similarly,
for $n$

$\begin{array}\\
W_{m, n}-\zeta(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{(k+1)^mk^{n}}-\frac1{k^{n}})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}(\frac{1}{(k+1)^m}-1)\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}(\frac{(k+1)^m-1}{(k+1)^m})\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(k+1)^mk^{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{m}{j}k^j\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(k+1)^mk^{n-j}}\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, n-j}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$W_{m, n}
=\zeta(n)-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{m}{j}W_{m, n-j}
$.