# Can $- (s^2 + (n + 1) s + n (n - 1)) \frac{\prod^{n - 2}_{^{} k = 1} (s - k)}{\prod^n_{k = 0} (s + k)}$ be written as a hypergeometric function?

Tags: summation, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Can

$$\begin{align}\sum_{m = 0}^n \frac{Y_{m, n, 4}}{m + s} & = - (s^2 + (n + 1) s + n (n -
    1)) \frac{\prod^{n - 2}_{^{} k = 1} (s - k)}{\prod^n_{k = 0} (s + k)}\\
    & = - (s^2 + (n + 1) s + n (n - 1)) \left( \frac{(- 1)^n \Gamma (n - s)
    \Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (1 - s) \Gamma (n + s + 1)} \right)\end{align}$$

be written as a hypergeometric function? We have the related sum
\begin{align}
    \sum_{m = 0}^n \frac{Y_{m, n, 3}}{m + s} & = \sum_{m = 0}^n (-
    1)^{m + n - 1} \frac{\Gamma (m + n - 1)}{\Gamma (m + 1)^2 \Gamma (n - m - 1)(m + s)}\\
    & = - \frac{(- 1)^n}{s}  \;_3 F_ 2 \left( \begin{array}{lll}
      s & (2 - n) & (n - 1)\\
      1 & s + 1 & 
    \end{array} \middle| 1 \right)
  \end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be shown that

$\begin{array}{ll}
  Y_{m, n, 4} & = {Res} (\hat{y}_{n, 4} (s), s = - m)\\
  & = \lim_{s = - m} (s + m) \hat{y}_{n, 4} (s)\\
  & = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    0 & n \leqslant 2\\
    \frac{(- 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m!^{})^2} \left( \prod_{k = 0}^{m - 1} (n - k)
    \right) \left( \prod_{k = 1}^{m - 2} (n + k) \right) (n^2 - (m + 1) n + m
    (m - 1)) & n \geqslant 3
  \end{array} \right.
\end{array}$

so that

$\begin{array}{ll}
  \begin{array}{l}
    \hat{y}_{n, 4} (s)
  \end{array} & = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{Y_{m, n, 4}}{m + s}\\
  & = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(- 1)^{m + n + 1}  (- 1)^m \Gamma (- n + m)
  \Gamma (n + m - 1)  (n^2 - (m + 1) n + m (m - 1))}{\Gamma (- n) \Gamma (n +
  1) (m!)^2  (m + s)}\\
  & = 
\end{array}$

$
- \frac{(- 1)^n}{s} 5 F 4 \left( \begin{array}{l}
    \begin{array}{lllll}
      {}[s] & [- n] & [n - 1] & \left[ - \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2} -
      \frac{1}{2}  \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6
      \hspace{0.17em} n + 1} \right] & \left[ - \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2} +
      \frac{1}{2}  \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6
      \hspace{0.17em} n + 1} \right]
    \end{array}\\
    \begin{array}{l}
      \begin{array}{llll}
        {}[1] & [s + 1] & \left[ - \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} 
        \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6 \hspace{0.17em} n +
        1} \right] & \left[ - \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} 
        \hspace{0.17em} \sqrt{- 3 \hspace{0.17em} n^2 + 6 \hspace{0.17em} n +
        1} \right]
      \end{array}
    \end{array}
  \end{array} \right)
$

well, whatever, tired of fighting latex, you get the point,

$\sum _{m=0}^{n}{\frac {{\it Y4} \left( m,n \right) }{m+s}}=-{\frac {
 \left( -1 \right) ^{n}
{\mbox{$_5$F$_4$}(s,-n,n-1,-n/2+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1},-n/2+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1};\,1,s+1,-n/2-1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1},-n/2-1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1};\,1)}
}{s}}+{\frac {n \left( n-1 \right) \Gamma  \left( 2\,n \right) 
{\mbox{$_6$F$_5$}(1,1,2\,n,s+1+n,n/2+3/2-1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1},n/2+3/2+1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1};\,n+2,n+2,2+n+s,n/2+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1},n/2+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{n}^{2}+6\,n+1};\,1)}
 \left( -1 \right) ^{3\,n}\sin \left( \pi \, \left( n+1 \right) 
 \right) }{ \left(  \left( n+1 \right) ! \right) ^{2} \left( s+1+n
 \right) \pi }}
$